# How to fetch outlook mails with particular keyword in subject using win32com in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I am trying to write a code which will print body of the mail if it came in past three days with a particular keyword in subject. For ex: 'approved' keyword here in my code. It should list contents of all the mails of past three days having approved as keyword in subject. Could you please suggest how to do that? 
Here is my working code, only filtering is required using 'approved' keyword:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import time
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

# this is set to the current time
date_time = dt.datetime.now()

# this is set to three days ago
lastThreeDaysDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 3)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

# retrieve all emails in the inbox, then sort them from most recently received to oldest (False will give you the reverse). Not strictly necessary, but good to know if order matters for your search
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

# restrict to messages from the past hour based on ReceivedTime using the dates defined above.
# lastHourMessages will contain only emails with a ReceivedTime later than an hour ago
# The way the datetime is formatted DOES matter; You can't add seconds here.

#lastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")
lastThreeDaysMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastThreeDaysDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")

#lastMinuteMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastMinuteDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")

print ("Current time: "+date_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'))
print ("Messages from the past three days:")

#GetFirst/GetNext will also work, since the restricted message list is just a shortened version of your full inbox.

#print ("Using GetFirst/GetNext")
message = lastThreeDaysMessages.GetFirst()
while message:
    #Here needs filter which should print only those mails having approved keyword
    print (message.subject)
    print (message.body)
    message = lastThreeDaysMessages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine both conditions into a single `Restrict` call:

```
lastThreeDaysMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastThreeDaysDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"' AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" ci_phrasematch " & "'approved'")
```

Read more about that in the [Creating Filters for the Find and Restrict Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict#creating-filters-for-the-find-and-restrict-methods) section in MSDN.

Comment: getting below error:
---> 25 lastThreeDaysMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastThreeDaysDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"' AND [Subject] ci_phrasematch " & "'approved'")
     26 #lastThreeDaysMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastThreeDaysDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")
     27 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Try to use `urn:schemas:httpmail:subject` instead of `[Subject]`

Comment: Since DASL queries always perform date-time comparisons in UTC, if you use a date literal in a comparison string, you must use its UTC value for the comparison.

Comment: showing invalid syntax:
lastThreeDaysMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastThreeDaysDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"' AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" ci_phrasematch " & "'approved'")
:( I did some trials but still showing invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of searching email with specific subject. I used python library called exchangelib for my project. Though my purpose/objective was different, but I believe exchangelib might be able to help you.

https://medium.com/@theamazingexposure/accessing-shared-mailbox-using-exchangelib-python-f020e71a96ab

Here is the python snippet where I am using exchangelib to look for the latest email with a specific subject:

for item in account.inbox.filter(**subject__contains='Data is ready for'**).order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]: